# How to visualize a point series within a grouped bar chart in Excel?

Tags: data-visualization, microsoft-excel

I have created a grouped bar chart within Excel, that shows the mean wage of men in different countries (y-axis), represented by different occupation groups (categories).

Now I want to enhance the chart by displaying the mean wage of women for the same countries and categories, meaning that for each value represented in the grouped bar chart, an additional value should be added, using points or points with lines.

The problem is that I do not know how to add the series of point data so that they are put to the according bar. When I add the point data, they are all put in the middle of the grouped bars, respectively, but not to the according bar.
Is there any possibility to achieve my desired result - does Excel provide an option I have not seen so far?

I hope the attached images can illustrate my problem. 
The yellow points should indicate the desired result and are placed to the chart by adding a point symbol and placing it manually to the chart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you describe you need a scatter chart on the secondary axis and adjust the x values to match the position of the bars. You basically need a separate data table for the women's salary with 1 to 24 on the X axis and the salaries on the Y axis. Adjust the X values until they match the bars perfectly.